# Wordpress > Set default homepage in install package

Tags: wordpress

I posted this over at the wordpress forums too but it seems like it takes days to weeks (at best) to ever get an answer over there, so:

I am building a custom install package and I've modified the "Sample Page" to be the actual default page I want (via the upgrade.php file). I would also like to modify the code for Settings > Reading > "A static page" and then set that id to be 2 which should be the default page I created.

I am unable to find this in the code. Does anyone know where this is stored so I can modify it so that after install this setting is already set?

Just had a thought...perhaps that codes not there because it never sets ANYTHING as the home page.  That would make sense.  In that case I'd need help constructing the code from someone already knowledgeable in tweaking WP. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an `option_name` in the `wp_options` table called `page_on_front`. It is likely not the *best* way, but you *can* set this directly with an SQL command.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 2 WHERE option_name = 'page_on_front';
```

**Note:** You may need to `INSERT INTO` as this option might not exist on initial install.

Comment: That'll work for me, there are a few other manual mysql commands I need to run during install as well.  I can just throw this one in there too. Thanks Jason.